# Computer briefly flashes tty screen right before shutdown or restart

Tags: shutdown, 15.04, tty

I recently upgraded to 15.04 from a fresh install and everything is working well so far, except when I shutdown or restart, the tty screen quickly flashes and then the purple ubuntu logo screen appears (like normal when starting up or shutting down). The shutdown time is still very quick and the tty screen doesn't hang or cause any problems, but I am trying to figure out why this is and how to fix it. Does anyone know how to solve this?